# Put/Get don't accept a string-valued expression as filename

Tags: export, files-and-directories

I'm trying to do the following with an expression:

```
filename=StringJoin[{"myfile", ToString[someNumber],".m"}];
expression >> filename;
```

But mathematica keeps creating a file named "filename", instead of "myfile42.m"

Any idea how can I tell `Put` to pretty please, use the filename string value, instead of the expression's name?

Comment: I have answered this question previously so I am marking this one as *already has an answer.*  Please see the link inserted at the top of your post.  In short use `Put` rather than `>>` and `Get` rather than `<<`.

Comment: In fact @Mr.Wizard I tried using the `Put` and `Get` form and the problem persisted. The correct solution was the one suggested by @Nasser using Evaluate

Comment: What version are you using and what is the output of `Attributes[{Get, Put}]`?  On my machine it is `{{Protected}, {Protected}}`.  That means these do not have Hold attributes and therefore `filename` *will* be evaluated.  What exactly did you try?

Comment: Also, did you read my answer?  Therein I explain why this behaves as it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put seems to treat the argument as literal and not evaluate it. i.e. it takes the argument `filename` as the actual filename and not its value. In Mathematica talk, this is called Holding its arguments.

Just do this:

```
  expression >> Evaluate@filename
```

Should work. Worked for me. Full example:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
somenumber = 10;
filename = StringJoin[{"myfile", ToString[somenumber], ".m"}];
2 >> Evaluate@filename
x = Get[Evaluate@filename];
x
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: it does indeed work with `Put`, but with `Get` I get: "Cannot open Evaluate"

Comment: @lurscher make sure your notebook is in same directory where you save the file? It works for me ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pFxPZ.png)  just do `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` before exporting.